# React-Native: Show loading screen till the webview is loaded

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I have at the moment a component SplashScreen which I'm rendering first till my state is set. I would like somehow to find a way how to still show this component while my webview is loaded. I added the onLoadEnd to my webview and looks like I get my message back when its finished loading, the problem is that if I load first the splashscreen and wait for the state to be changed onLoadEnd actually will never be changed because the webview is not yet rendered. Is there a good method how to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

My solution was actually quite simple, the WebView component can have the param renderLoading which for me was not working, I figured out it was because also startInLoadingState needed to be defined.

So my WebView looks somehow like this:

```
<WebView
   ref={MY_REF}
   source={source}
   renderLoading={this.renderLoading}
   startInLoadingState
/>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Works like a charm.
For renderLoading, you even can use an arrowfunction like:
`renderLoading={()=>{return(<ActivityIndicator/>}`
but this has also a little Bug for me. If you load the Indicator by arrow-Funktion it is placed on top, centerd.
With default-local function :
`function renderLoading(){
return(<ActivityIndicator/>);
}
` and loadign it like you described, it's well placed centerd in the middle of the screen.
I have no clue why, but maybe this helps someone to save some time :)

Comment: Thanks, this is the way to go, or as suther commented `renderLoading={()=>{return(<ActivityIndicator/>)}` but the loader position has nothing to do with how you declare or call your function! If you do not style your ActivityIndicator component it will just appear on top horizontaly centered. To make ti centered verticaly also add style like so:
`<ActivityIndicator style = {{position: 'absolute',left: 0,right: 0, top: 0,bottom: 0,alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center'}}/>`

Answer (score 14):

This would be my approach:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { webviewLoaded: false };
}

_onLoadEnd() {
    this.setState({ webviewLoaded: true });
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            {(this.state.webviewLoaded) ? null : <SplashScreen />}
            <WebView onLoadEnd={this._onLoadEnd.bind(this)} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

This way, the webview is rendered but it is placed behind the `SplashScreen`. So the webview starts loading while the `SplashScreen` is being displayed.

Comment: Looks like in this case my state is not changing and the splash screen its loaded just in the top of the screen.

Comment: did you put the source for the WebView?

Comment: Basically the onLoadEnd method its not runned when the webview finished loading.

Comment: I meant did you put the source prop in your WebView? I tested it. your <SplashScreen /> should cover the entire screen. use Dimensions to get the width and height of the screen.

Comment: I was able to do it sucessfully

Comment: Looks like it works like this to show full the SplashScreen but I still have a problem that my state will never change on the method onLoadEnd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124505/discussion-between-ninetyhh-and-jan-franz-palngipang).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I managed to solve it temporarily with this:

```
loadEnd () {
 this.setState({ webViewLoaded: true }):
}
render () {
const { webViewLoaded } = this.state;
return (<View> 
      {!webViewLoaded && <LoadingComponent /> } -- or spinner, whatever

         <WebView 
            style={(webViewLoaded) ? styles.webView : styles.loading}
            onLoadEnd={() => this.loadEnd.bind(this)} /> 
      </View);

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  webView: { -- your styles ---},
  loading: {
    width: 0,
    heigt: 0
  }
});
```

not sure if exactly this helps you but you can try similar approach. I will probably change this to something more convenient. Not sure if there are possibilities to animate these changes because Im still pretty newbie in React Native.

edit: added hiding the spinner/loading element